# Reading pixel values in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have read the pixel values of the image and saved them in a .txt file, but i want to have only 0 and 255 in my txt file

i have done some coding and the code compiled successfully but the txt file doesnt open.

plzzz help me out.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
    try
  {
    throw 20;
  }
  catch (int e)
  {
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << '\n';
  }


    Mat colorImage = imread(path);

    // Open the file in write mode.
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("name.txt");

    // Iterate through pixels.
    for (int r = 0; colorImage.rows < r ; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; colorImage.cols < c ; c++)
          {

            int pixel = colorImage.at<uchar>(r,c);


            if ( pixel < 70)
            { 
                pixel = 0;
            }
            else pixel = 255;

            outputFile << pixel << '\t';
        }
        outputFile << endl;
    }

    // Close the file.
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add try-catch as in `int main(int argc, char** argv) { try { ... } catch (exception& e) { cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;` as described, say, at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/ and tell about the exception? I see you are new to C++, maybe to writing code too, don't let the downvotes to discourage. :)

Comment: Thank you for ur support, i will try to add the try-catch.

Comment: Hey i got it , thank u so much

Comment: You could add an answer to your own question so that we get a proper conclusion. :)

Comment: the main problem was in the code, if condition wasnt right, so I rectified it and I edited the code above.